# Swap <div> content from pure css menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to fix my jquery issue where I swap  content from separate html pages stored in multiple sub folders.  My menu has over 100 link items that I need to work with on my site.  Links 1-4 work well and swap without issue but any beyond that cease to function. The initial code I sourced off the net.  Just not sure why it's not working fully as I need all 100+ links active. Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

The below code is part of the CSS menu.  link1, link2, link3, and link4 all work as they should but beyond that nothing seems to function.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a id="link1" href="#" onmouseover="roll('but1', 'images/blueeye/blueeye_b1_over.png')" onmouseout="roll('but1', 'images/blueeye/blueeye_b1.png')">
        <img alt="Home" src="images/blueeye/blueeye_b1.png" name="but1" class="style3" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:vold(0)" onmouseover="roll('but2', 'images/blueeye/blueeye_b2_over.png')" onmouseout="roll('but2', 'images/blueeye/blueeye_b2.png')">
        <img alt="Worship Programs" src="images/blueeye/blueeye_b2.png" name="but2" class="style3" /></a>
        <ul style="width: 170px">
            <li><a id="link2" href="#">Our Worship Program</a></li>
            <li><a id="link3" href="#">Sabbath School</a></li>
            <li><a id="link4" href="#">Divine Service</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:vold(0)" onmouseover="roll('but3', 'images/blueeye/blueeye_b3_over.png')" onmouseout="roll('but3', 'images/blueeye/blueeye_b3.png')">
        <img alt="Sabbath School" src="images/blueeye/blueeye_b3.png" name="but3" class="style3" /></a>
        <ul style="width: 160px">
            <li><a id="link5" href="#">Current Lesson</a></li>
            <li><a id="link6" href="#">Mission Story</a></li>
            <li><a id="link7" href="#">Adult Lessons</a></li>
            <li><a id="link8" href="#">PowerPoint Helps</a></li>
            <li><a id="link9" href="#">Picture Memory Verses</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The below javascript is the  swapping.  As stated above link1-link4 all function but link5 onwards doesn't.

Code begins here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#link1").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("homepage.htm");});
$("#link2").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("about/worship-program.htm");});
$("#link3").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("about/ss_worship.htm");});
$("#link4").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("about/div_worship.htm");});

$("#link5").click(function(){$("#site_content_ss").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-lesson-current.htm");});
$("#link6").click(function(){$("#site_content_ss").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-mission-story.htm");});
$("#link7").click(function(){$("#site_content_ss").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-lesson-pdf.htm");});
$("#link8").click(function(){$("#site_content_ss").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-lesson-pptx.htm");});
$("#link9").click(function(){$("#site_content_ss").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-lesson-memory-verse.htm");});
$("#link10").click(function()$("#site_content").load("kjv_bible/kjv_bible.htm");});
$("#link11").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("");});
$("#link12").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("");});
$("#link13").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("");});
$("#link14").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("");});
</script>
```

Comment: In what way does it not working and is there any error in the console?

Comment: it doesn't swap content when you click a link beyond #Link4

Comment: Really you shouldn't be swapping content, just display:none/block/inline-block what you need...

Comment: I'm running off a single page and loading div content from external pages to reduce time and space.

Answer (score 0):

1. please check that #site_content_ss exists,
2. unexpected identifier

this part:

```
$("#link10").click(function()$("#site_content").load("kjv_bible/kjv_bible.htm");});
```

should be this:

```
$("#link10").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("kjv_bible/kjv_bible.htm");});
```

I'd create a example  https://jsbin.com/muvoyuredu/edit?html,js,output

**UPDATE**

if you would to swap content into #site_content

```
        $("#link5").click(function(){$("#site_content_ss").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-lesson-current.htm");});
        $("#link6").click(function(){$("#site_content_ss").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-mission-story.htm");});
        $("#link7").click(function(){$("#site_content_ss").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-lesson-pdf.htm");});
        $("#link8").click(function(){$("#site_content_ss").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-lesson-pptx.htm");});
        $("#link9").click(function(){$("#site_content_ss").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-lesson-memory-verse.htm");});
```

should be this:

```
        $("#link5").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-lesson-current.htm");});
        $("#link6").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-mission-story.htm");});
        $("#link7").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-lesson-pdf.htm");});
        $("#link8").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-lesson-pptx.htm");});
        $("#link9").click(function(){$("#site_content").load("weekly_updates/sabbath_school/ss-lesson-memory-verse.htm");});
```

**if you want stay on selected div block on refresh**

1. href `#` change to `#id` (e.g. `href="#link1"` )
2. get id in the query string than auto click this link

I'd create a example https://jsbin.com/cocuvaraqu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: sample site = www.yourlife-godsword.net/test_site/

Comment: the { was removed when adjusting the code here.  it's there on the page.

Comment: please change #site_content_ss to #site_content

Comment: changed it to site_content and it worked.  Thanks, although in the beginning it was set at that and didn't work.  It is now though.  How do I stop it returning to default page on refresh and stay on selected div block?

Comment: try using id by querystring when you want stay on selected div block(ex. https://jsbin.com/cocuvaraqu/edit?html,js,output)